# Opening a div with content after clicking a button

Tags: html

I´m building a website in which i want the content to pop up in a div after clicking a menu button instead of going to another html page.

I have the menu built with a unordered list but i cant seem to solve this using the visibility css property.

Is there a way to do this?

I´m not in a hurry, just training my programming skills so this website is just for playing around a little bit.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can check about modal windows in http://getbootstrap.com

Comment: Have you tried "Display: None" to hide, and "Display: initial" to show? http://www.css3.com/display/

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I tried to use the Display property but might be doing something wrong. I´ve set the HTML with this line: <div id="Sobre" style="display: none">Content Div</div> and then in the Css i´ve coded this: #Sobre {
    display: initial;
} but it doesn´t work

Comment: Michael and meeming: i´ve explained myself wrong. It´s not a pop up window i want to show but a simple area with content after you press a link. My menu is composed of the following links: About, Facts, Top5, History, Through the world. After i press a link a div with the corresponding content shows up below the menu. I will also try to give a transition and curtain like effect or something but that will be made after i can make the div to show up

Answer (score 1):

It's called lightbox.
You need adding the click event Listener to a button,and hide the popped up Div at first,then show it when button clicked.
The popped up Div must align center of the screen,so you must add the event Listener of window Resize.
Maybe a modal also is needed.
If you write this by hand,browser compatibility is also tedious.
Use plug-ins is convenient. 
There are so many good plug-ins that can be used easily.
I recommend [jQuery fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)